# How do I integrate Google Login under a Cake PHP framework

Tags: cakephp, authentication, oauth, cakephp-1.3

I have been trying to integrate Google login to one of my sites that is being developed using CakePHP framework. So far I have been unsuccessful in doing so. Does anybody have any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Which version of CakePHP are you using ?

However, you should take a look to that thread : [CakePHP OAuth with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741501/cakephp-oauth-with-google)

There is also good ressources on CakePHP / providers authentications :

- https://github.com/corefactor/CakePHP-Oauth-Plugin
- http://code.42dh.com/oauth/
- http://code.42dh.com/openid/
- http://cutfromthenorth.com/integrating-facebook-connect-with-cakephps-auth-component/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have been using version 1.3.

Comment: While this is great set of resources, and ultimately useful, this suggestion is at best a link-only "answer", which is to dry that it is a Comment, not an Answer, according to SO guidelines for Answers. It is a perfect example of the type response that Comments are designed for. Additionally, Q's like this, that do not meet the criteria for the type Q's SO is designed to handle, should be closed, and answered via Comments, rather than the Answer section.

Comment: This question is pretty old now, but if you are looking for a complete tutorial for CakePHP 3 Google login, take a look here https://www.cakedc.com/jorge_gonzalez/2016/10/11/login-with-google-oauth2-in-cakephp-using-cakedc-users-plugin

Answer (score -1):

Hiii ...Pls Follow Step by step .

Step 1: First of all , U should download Google files From github or any in ../app/Vendor directory ....
Make sure that Google files includes following files ..

Auth folder, cache folder, contrib folder, external folder,io folder,service folder & autoload.php file,config.php file, Google_Client.php file .

Step 2 : Create Users table .

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (<br>
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,<br>
  `first_name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `last_name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `email` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `password` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `social_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `picture` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `uuid` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),<br>
  KEY `email_idx` (`email`)<br>
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

NOTE : All Fields are not mandatory . Ur wish .

Step 3: Then U should  Create Client ID & Client Secret key for your app/website at https://developers.google.com/

Refer : https://theonetechnologies.com/blog/post/how-to-get-google-app-client-id-and-client-secret for steps .

Step 4 : Now you should have your own Client ID & Client Secret key.

Step 5: Add these five lines in your ../app/config/bootstrap.php file

```
define('GOOGLE_APP_NAME', 'Smart Quiz');<br>
define('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR CLIENT_ID');<br>
define('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET', 'YOUR CLIENT_SECRET');<br>
define('GOOGLE_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI', 'http://localhost/cakelogin/google_login');<br>
define("GOOGLE_SITE_NAME", 'https://your site/');
```

& fill your Client Id , Secret key , Redirect URI & site url .

Ex format:

```
Client id : xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com<br>
    Secret key : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx<br>
    Redirect URI : https://your site/google/google_login
```

NOTE : Redirect uri (i.e) your site should be "https" . It won't allow http site .

Step 6: Create google_login.php file in the app/Config directory and including following files. Here is my code.

```
<?php<

require_once '../Vendor/Google/src/config.php';
require_once '../Vendor/Google/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../Vendor/Google/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';
require_once '../Vendor/Google/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
```

NOTE : Make sure the Vendor directory path & file locations are in correct .

Step 7 : In view file , add this link in

```
href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=YOUR REDIRECT URI&client_id=YOUR CLIENT ID.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email+profile&access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto"
```

Step 8: Create GoogleController . Copy below Code.

```
App::import('Vendor', 'google', array('file' => 'google/config.php'));<br>
App::import('Vendor', 'google', array('file' => 'google/Google_Client.php'));<br>
App::import('Vendor', 'google', array('file' => 'google/contrib/Google_PlusService.php'));<br>
App::import('Vendor', 'google', array('file' => 'google/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php'));<br>



class GoogleController extends AppController {<br>
    public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session');<br>
    public $uses = array('User');<br>
    public $layout = '';<br>

    public function google_login() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        require_once '../Config/google_login.php';
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');

        $plus = new Google_PlusService($client);
        $oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $client->authenticate(); // Authenticate
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken(); // get the access token here<br>
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        }

        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
            $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
            try {
                if (!empty($user)) {
                    $check = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('email' => $user['email'], 'status !=' => 'Trash')));
                    if (empty($check)) {
                        $data = array();
                        $data['email'] = $user['email'];
                        $data['name'] = $user['given_name'];
                        $data['user_name'] = $this->random_username($user['given_name']);
                        $this->User->save($data);

                        $id = $this->User->getLastInsertID();
                        $currentuser = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $id, 'status !=' => 'Trash')));

                        $this->Session->write('User', $currentuser['User']);
                        $this->Session->write('Userlogin', TRUE);

                        $this->Session->setFlash('Logged in Successfully !', '', array(''), 'front_success');
                        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'profile', 'controller' => 'users'));
                    } else {
                        $this->Session->write('User', $check['User']);
                        $this->Session->write('Userlogin', TRUE);
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Logged in Successfully !', '', array(''), 'front_success');
                        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'profile', 'controller' => 'users'));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(GOOGLE_LOGIN_FAILURE, 'default', array('class' => 'message error'), 'error');
                $this->redirect(BASE_PATH . 'login');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step 9 : In app/Vendor/google/config.php file , u can see the application name , oauth2_client_id ,  oauth2_client_secret, oauth2_redirect_uri . So you have to give ur details on that . Example :

```
'application_name' => 'YOUR APPLICATION NAME',<br>
 'oauth2_client_id' => 'YOUR CLIENT ID',<br>
 'oauth2_client_secret' => 'YOUR SECRET KEY',<br>
 'oauth2_redirect_uri' => 'https://your site/google/google_login', <br>
```

Thats it !   :)

Problems that i faced is , I wrongly mention the REDIRECT URI in facebook developers & in Config.php file . So You should provide same Redirect path in your bootstrap.php file , config.php file , href="" link & in developers site .

Hope it will help ... Thank You .

Comment: Please edit to meet SO guidelines, which requires proper grammar and spelling (and remove help/please/thanks/etc cruft). Readability is hindered, post is low quality, and communication is hindered when words are omitted, sentences are incomplete, and spelling is purposely incorrect. It's lazy. Code is difficult enough, without sentences written in a custom shortcut language too. Refer to https://StackOverflow.com/help sections for more details.

Comment: SO is not a tutorial provider. This question should have been closed, not answered by providing a tutorial. You could instead write a tutorial, on another website, then post a link *as a Comment* to the OP's post.